# Fixed: Unknown geocoding error on Nominatim (Open street maps)

Tags: civievent, error, geocoding

we use maps for CiviEvent, but now we always get this error message:

Unknown geocoding error on :Nominatim (Open street maps):The geocoder server returned an invalid response (404) for query "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/search?format=jsonv2&q=Ulmenstr.%2015%2CBad%20Saarow%2C15526%2CBrandenburg%2CDeutschland&addressdetails=1&extratags=1&limit=5&accept-language=de". We could not parse it.

We use OpenStreetMaps via Geocoder (no Google). How do I get the API-key?

Kind regards,
Regina

---

CiviCRM 5.58.1. with WordPress 6.3

Comment: if you don't get answers to your specific question about the API key, would it be an acceptable solution to just generate the Lat Long yourself and enter those?

Answer (score 3):

this is a known issue in the Geocoder extension and should be fixed in the latest version (1.10 as of today). Please note that Geocoder 1.9+ requires CiviCRM 5.60+. If you need to stay on 5.58.1, you can also use Geocoder 1.8 and manually fix the wrong url causing this error in the database. Simply change https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search to https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ in the civicrm_geocoder table (column: url).
You won't need an API key for Openstreetmap.

Comment: Thank you so much, Andreas. Issue fixed ;-)